# The transaction associated with the current connection has completed but has not been disposed

Tags: 2013, cme

I am using SDL Tridion 2013 SP1, while saving a large Component I am getting the following error:

> (80040356) The transaction associated with the current connection has completed but has not been disposed. The transaction must be disposed before the connection can be used to execute SQL statements. Unable to save item

Answer (score 6):

This most often points to a database timeout. Possible ways to solve it are: increase database timeout in MMC and do some maintenance on the database

Comment: With the emphasis on **do some maintenance on the database**, so that you most likely will not have to increase the timeout.

Comment: i m getting same error after increasing timeout the error is coming in less then 5 second .what type of maintenance i have to do on database.